# User Input Insertion

Tags: java, jdbc

I wanted to insert 100 records into my database. This is my code but I get an inputmismatchexception. Could someone tell me Whats wrong with my code? I am new to Java JDBC.

```
    int count = 0;
    while (count < 100) {
    String emp = sc.nextLine();
    int sal = sc.nextInt();
    int empid = sc.nextInt();

    try {

        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/practice","root","admin");
        Statement st = con.createStatement();
        int rs = st.executeUpdate("insert into practicetable values ('"+emp+"','"+sal+"','"+empid+"')");
        System.out.println("success");
        count++;

}catch(Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
    }
```

}
}

Comment: Your problem has nothing to do with JDBC, it has to do with how you use `java.util.Scanner`. And please, post a [mcve] and include the full exception stacktrace.

Comment: And please, learn about prepared statements. Your current code which concatenates values into the insert statement is extremely unsafe.

Answer (score 0):

You need to read (and omit) the break line when reading integers:

```
String emp = sc.nextLine();
int sal = sc.nextInt();
//read and omit the break line
sc.nextLine();
int empid = sc.nextInt();
```